# determine maximum remaining teams in a round robin tournament

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let's say I have 10 teams competing in a round-robin tournament. Ties are not allowed, and only teams that have at least 7 wins can move on to a new tournament. How would I go about proving the maximum number of teams that could reach 7 wins and move on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know too much about combinatories, but I found a solution!

45 games are played in total, so I would go this way to get some upper bounds:

We first assume that 7 teams qualify, but this would require the sum of wins from those 7 teams to be at least 49, which cannot happen.

Therefore, the soutuion has to be 6 or less, but 6 is also out of the question, since the other 4 teams play 6 games among themselves, so the sum of the top 6 teams has to be 39 or less.

So we are left with 5 at best, where 5 teams can get at most 35 wins, and... there is a concrete solution!

Teams A,B,C,D and E beat every game against teams F,G,H,I and J.

A beats B and C,

B beats C and D,

C beats D and E,

D beats A and E,

E beats A and B

Teams A,B,C,D and E have 7 wins each!

I am not exactly sure how this reasoning generalizes, though!